# Generate aligned requirements.txt and dev-requirements.txt with pip-compile

Tags: python, requirements.txt, pyproject.toml, pip-tools, pip-compile

I have a Python project that depends on two packages `moduleA` and `moduleB`. I have the following `pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = "meta-motor"
version = "3.1.0.dev"
dependencies = [
    "moduleA==1.0.0"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "moduleB==1.0.0"
]
```

with `moduleA` depending on `moduleC>=1.0.0` and `moduleB` depending on `moduleC==1.1.0`.

I compile my requirements.txt and dev-requirements.txt like this:

```
$ pip-compile -o requirements.txt pyproject.toml 
$ pip-compile --extra dev -o dev-requirements.txt pyproject.toml
```

With this, I get

*requirements.txt*

```
moduleA==1.0.0
    # via pyproject.toml
moduleC==1.2.0
    # via moduleA
```

*dev-requirements.txt*

```
moduleB==1.0.0
    # via pyproject.toml
moduleA==1.0.0
    # via pyproject.toml
moduleC==1.1.0
    # via 
    #   moduleB
    #   moduleA
```

As you can see, the `moduleC` version is different in both `requirements.txt` files.
How can I solve this so I have `moduleC==1.1.0` in both ?

I could specify `moduleC==1.1.0` in my `pyproject.toml`, but this is not practicable for larger project with lots of dependencies like this.

Comment: "ecdsa version"..?

Comment: Maybe generate `dev-requirements.txt` first and then use it as "constraints" when generating `requirements.txt`. It seems like this is more or less what is described in ["*Workflow for layered requirements*"](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/tree/6.13.0#workflow-for-layered-requirements).

Comment: Using your link, I can get something to work using 2 `requirements.in` and `dev-requirements.in` files, which is nice. Just wondering if I could somehow still use the `pyproject.toml` as input, but I'm doubting it. I will post an answer and close this question if I don't find anything in a few days.

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading the doc `pip-compile` can take a `pyproject.toml` as input. -- I am a bit confused by your question because everything you seem to be asking for is quite clearly documented on the first page of the doc of *pip-tools*...

Answer (score 1):

This PR [#1936](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/pull/1936) introduces `-c/--constraint` option to `pip-compile` which allows you to pass `requirements.txt` as a constraint file when compiling `dev-requirements.txt`, for example:

```
$ pip-compile --extra dev -o dev-requirements.txt -c requirements.txt pyproject.toml
```

This should resolve the issue.